# C++ Tic Tac Toe project

Tags: c++

I'm now working on a Tic Tac Toe project. I'm having the problem that whenever I input into the console an ordinate,for example [6][0] (and the program will put the mark 'X' or 'O' into that position) for an array with the size of [15][15],it will automatically save the mark 'X' or 'O' into another position which is not in the array range (in my case is [5][15]).This is my program (P/S: I'm Vietnamese so just ignore the parts that are in Vietnamese):

```
int size = 15;
int inputAmount;
int inputX = 0;
int inputY = 0;
char board[15][15];
bool checkWin = false;
char mark = 'X';

// Interdisciplinary examination of scale loss
bool checkWinLose() {
    int max;
    int x,y;
    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;

    // Looking horizontally under investigation
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x - 1][y] && board[x - 1][y] == board[x - 2][y]))
        {
            cout << "Game over ngang!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        x++;
    }

    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;
    max = 0;
    // Interdisciplinary examination of vertical
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x][y - 1] && board[x][y - 1] == board[x][y - 2]))
        {
            cout << "Game over doc!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        y++;
    }

    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;
    max = 0;
    // Interdisciplinary examination of under the cliff cave from left to right
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x - 1][y - 1] && board[x - 1][y - 1] == board[x - 2][y - 2]))
        {
            cout << "Game over trai sang phai!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        x++;
        y++;
    }

    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;
    max = 0;
    // Interdisciplinary examination of under the cliff cave from right to left
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x + 1][y - 1] && board[x + 1][y - 1] == board[x + 2][y - 2]))
        {
            cout << "Game over phai sang trai!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        x--;
        y++;
    }

    // Flower test case
    if (inputAmount == 225)
    {
        cout << "Game over hoa!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

// Lay-coordinate of the muon practice player list
void takeInput() {
    do {
        // Lay gia tri toa do x
        do {
            cout << "Please choose the horizontal (rightward) number (smaller than " << size + 1 << "): ";
            cin >> inputX;
        } while ((inputX > size) || (inputX <= 0));
        // Lay y coordinate values
        do {
            cout << "Please choose the vertical (downward) number (smaller than " << size + 1 << "): ";
            cin >> inputY;
        } while ((inputY > size) || (inputY <= 0));
        inputX--;
        inputY--;
        if (board[inputX][inputY] != '.')
            cout << "Already chosen!" << endl ;
    } while (board[inputX][inputY] != '.');
    board[inputX][inputY] = mark;
    if (mark == 'X')
        mark = 'O';
    else
        mark = 'X';
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
}

// Hien game board on the screen
void loadGameboard () {
    int x,y;

    ////TODO: check win or lose
    while (!checkWin) {
        for (; y < size ; y++)
        {
            for (; x < size ; x++)
            {
                cout << board[x][y] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            x = 0;
        }
        checkWin = checkWinLose();
        if (checkWin == true)
            return;
        x,y = 0;
        takeInput();
        inputAmount++;
    }
}

// At first preparation game board
void prepareGameboard () {
    int x,y;

    for (; y < size ; y++)
    {
        for (; x < size ; x++)
        {
            board[x][y] = '.' ;
        }
        x = 0;
    }
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    char reset = 'y';
    do {
        prepareGameboard();
        loadGameboard();
        checkWin = 0;
        inputAmount = 0;
        cout << "Do you want to replay ? (y/n): ";
        cin >> reset;
        if ((reset == 'y') || (reset == 'Y'))
        {
            system("CLS");
        }
    } while ((reset == 'y') || (reset == 'Y'));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I translated the comments into English with Google Translate. It is hard to follow the program without knowing what it does. You can translate it into English on your own but this makes the program easier to read.

Comment: That is tremendous effort @john

Answer (score 0):

I would change `x,y = 0` to `x = y = 0` at line 123 in the code you pasted. And also add `return 0` to the function `checkWinLose()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the values for `x` and `y` in ther `for`'s.

Try to use :

```
void prepareGameboard () {
    int x,y;

    for (y = 0; y < size ; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < size ; x++)
        {
            board[x][y] = '.' ;
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
void loadGameboard () {
    int x,y;

    ////TODO: check win or lose
    while (!checkWin) {
        for (y = 0; y < size ; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < size ; x++)
            {
                cout << board[x][y] << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        checkWin = checkWinLose();
        if (checkWin == true)
            return;
        takeInput();
        inputAmount++;
    }
}
```

Also, like @Heinz said, and a `return 0;` at the end of the `checkWinLose` function;

Looking at your code, I believe the you are assuming the `int` always are initialized with 0 and that `checkWinLose` will return 0 by the default. Local variables have undefined initialization values and when no explicity return is called, the function just return so 'garbage' value.

Try to always add the returned value to the functons and initialize your variables (specially counters).

**Update**

This is how the function `checkWinLose` should be with the `return 0;`

```
// Interdisciplinary examination of scale loss
bool checkWinLose() {
    int max;
    int x,y;
    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;

    // Looking horizontally under investigation
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x - 1][y] && board[x - 1][y] == board[x - 2][y]))
        {
            cout << "Game over ngang!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        x++;
    }

    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;
    max = 0;
    // Interdisciplinary examination of vertical
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x][y - 1] && board[x][y - 1] == board[x][y - 2]))
        {
            cout << "Game over doc!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        y++;
    }

    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;
    max = 0;
    // Interdisciplinary examination of under the cliff cave from left to right
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x - 1][y - 1] && board[x - 1][y - 1] == board[x - 2][y - 2]))
        {
            cout << "Game over trai sang phai!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        x++;
        y++;
    }

    x = inputX;
    y = inputY;
    max = 0;
    // Interdisciplinary examination of under the cliff cave from right to left
    for (; max < 3; max++)
    {
        if ((board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') && (board[x][y] == board[x + 1][y - 1] && board[x + 1][y - 1] == board[x + 2][y - 2]))
        {
            cout << "Game over phai sang trai!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        x--;
        y++;
    }

    // Flower test case
    if (inputAmount == 225)
    {
        cout << "Game over hoa!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0; //<- Returning false if the all other tests failed
}
```

Comment: Tks man,but that is not really the solution to my problem.Can you solve the problem ???

Comment: Making the changes I said and adding the 'return 0;' made your program work in my computer

Comment: Actually I think that you misunderstand my program's problem.The problem is when I input an coordinate like board[7][1] (after minus is board[6][0]),it will safe the mark's value to board[5][15] (after minus)(not in the range of the array),which makes the program end when I input 2 others coordinate: board[6][14] and board[7][13] (after minus).Can you solve it for me ???

Comment: This error it is not happening with me. After the changes, it marks the correct position in board

Comment: Yeah mine,too.I mean that it will automatically save the value to another place which is now shown cuz it's not in the defining range